# Python rounding issue need to round half up every single digit

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

I am not sure if anyone has any bright ideas about scenarios like the following:

```
import math
from decimal import *

def apply_precision_scale(value, precision, scale):
    # supported formats:
    # time: precision: 7, scale 4
    # amplitude: precision: 7, scale: 5
    getcontext().rounding = ROUND_HALF_UP
    
    value_int = math.trunc(value)
    rounded_input = None

    # supports negative numbers
    if precision == 7 and scale == 5:
        if (value_int >= 0 and value_int <= 99) or \
           (value_int >= -99 and value_int < 0):
             places = scale
        elif (value_int >= 100 and value_int <= 999) or \
             (value_int <= -100 and value_int >= -999):
             places = scale - 1
        elif (value_int >= 1000 and value_int <= 9999) or \
             (value_int >= -1000 and value_int >= -9999):
             places = scale - 2
        elif (value_int >= 10000 and value_int <= 99999) or \
             (value_int >= -10000 and value_int >= -99999):
             places = scale - 3          
        elif (value_int >= 100000 and value_int <= 999999) or \
             (value_int >= -100000 and value_int >= -999999):
             places = scale - 4           
        elif (value_int >= 1000000 and value_int <= 9999999) or \
             (value_int >= -1000000 and value_int >= -9999999):
             places = scale - 5
        else:
            print("Error: The value exceeds allowed precision")
            return None
    elif precision == 7 and scale == 4:
        if (value_int >= 0 and value_int <= 999) or \
           (value_int <= -100 and value_int >= -999):
             places = scale
        elif (value_int >= 1000 and value_int <= 9999) or \
             (value_int >= -1000 and value_int >= -9999):            
             places = scale - 1
        elif (value_int >= 10000 and value_int <= 99999) or \
             (value_int >= -10000 and value_int >= -99999):
             places = scale - 2
        elif (value_int >= 100000 and value_int <= 999999) or \
             (value_int >= -100000 and value_int >= -999999):
             places = scale - 3
        elif (value_int >= 1000000 and value_int <= 9999999) or \
             (value_int >= -1000000 and value_int >= -9999999):
             places = scale - 4
        else:
            print("Error: The value exceeds allowed precision")
            return None
    else:
        print("Error: Unrecognized precision and scale format")
        return None

    return float(round(Decimal(value), places))
```

```
def verify_time_increments(voltages):
    i = 2
    failures = 0
    keys = list(voltages)
    increment = 0.001953125
    increment_list = [(apply_precision_scale(increment * i, 7, 4)) for i in range(len(keys) + 1) if i != 0]
    
    for index, time in enumerate(voltages):
        try:
            expected_time = increment_list[index]
            i += 1
        except IndexError: # mismatch between number of voltages and values in increment list
            print(index)
            print(len(increment_list))
```

The data comes in the following format and continues until the time data points end:
[image]

Voltages is a dictionary in the following format [0.002:-34.54, 0.0039:-35.65, etc]

For some reason I am getting errors on large numbers like this:
Expected: 64.0605
Actual: 64.0606
Expected: 64.123
Actual: 64.1231

In the first example, the value I am dealing with is 64.060546875 and the second case is 64.123046785. I am trying to cut them down to 4 significant digits but to round every digit up, meaning 46875 portion would be rounded to 50000, so 64.060546875 would be rounded to 64.0606.

Sample input file: https://controlc.com/d4a3d3ba

Comment: First, your rounding protocol is not at all clear.  You round a 5-digit number to *one* significant digit, but you keep four decimal places on 64.0605...

Comment: You should be able to tell that I am dealing with both precision and scale. In other words, given precision of 7 and scale of 4, for a number like 124.5435454, it is rounded to 4 decimal points, but for a number like 12545.5435353, it is rounded to 2 decimal points.

Comment: If you want precise results, you should work with `Decimal` values throughout, rather than passing in a floating-point number and converting back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if anyone has any bright ideas

How about this one? Mathematically, you're actually doing the wrong thing, trying to round individual digits well past the rounding point.

There's a reason why rounding only checks the digit immediately after the last one you want in the answer.

The idea is to minimise the error, and choose the *closest* value based on how many digits you want. The closest four-decimal-place value to `64.060546875` is `64.0605`, as shown in the following table:

```
Value:   64.050546875   64.050546875
Round:   64.0505        64.0506
Error:    0.000046875    0.000053125
```

Hence the `64.0505` rounded value is a better approximation to the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

I guess nobody understood that I was trying to do a ROUND_UP instead of ROUND_HALF_UP. This would have fixed my issue.